# how to call external webservice in salesforce APEX

Tags: web-services, salesforce

I'm new to SFDC. I need to perform integration between SFDC and EBS. I have a SOAP webservice from EBS to create party,account, account site and site details.

Now i need to call this webservice in SFDC(using APEX). Can you please let me know how i can achieve this (Expecting Step by step explanation) or any document which will tell me how this can be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce provides an integrated tool called Wsdl2Apex. It can be used to create Apex classes from the WSDL to call the web service from Apex. See [SOAP Services: Defining a Class from a WSDL Document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_wsdl2apex.htm), which includes step by step instructions on how to generate the Apex classes from a WSDL.

Remember that you will also need to setup a [Remote Site](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_remote_site_settings.htm) to allow the callout to the web service URL.

There are a couple of alternatives depending on how complicated your WSDL is.

Firstly, there is also an open source version of Wsdl2Apex.

Secondly, I've created an independent tool that has increased support for various WSDL features. See [Dreamforce 2014 Presentation - Improved Apex support for SOAP based web services](http://www.fishofprey.com/2014/11/dreamforce-2014-presentation-improved.html).